# Dynamically reference named list elements in for loop R

Tags: r

I am trying to loop through a number of named elements in a list, using the loop indices as the reference, as so:

```
for (i in ref1){
  for (j in 1:2){
      for (k in ref2){
        Count <- nrow(subset(list$`i.j.k`, var >=0))
       }
   }
}
```

The problem I am running into is that when I run the loop, it doesn't fill in the indices in the

```
lists$`i.j.k`
```

term, and so runs into the error of trying to find the "i.j.k" entry in the list, which doesn't exist. I haven't been able to find anyone having a similar problem. How can I make it fill in the values for i, j, and k so that it will reference the correct element? Thanks.

Comment: Is the list nested? If so, try `list[i][j][k]`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @LAP, but the list is not nested.

Comment: It is not clear about the question.  Please show a small reproducible example.  Try `list[[paste(i,j, k, sep=".")]]`

Comment: Read help("[").